# A direct result from the definition of operator norm: $\|Av\|\leq \|A\|_{op} \|v\|$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, normed-spaces, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, spectral-norm

Although Wikipedia says this result comes from the definition of Operator Norm directly, I am not quite sure how to understand it:

Let $\|\cdot\|$ denote Euclidean norm. Given a $n\times n$ matrix $A$, $\forall v\in R^n$, we have $\|Av\|\leq \|A\|_{op} \|v\|$.

The definition of operator norm is $\|A\|_{op}=\sup_{\|x\|\leq 1, \|x\|\in R^n} \|Ax\|$. Probably, we need to apply Cauchy-Schwartz inequality here, but then we need $\|A\|\leq \|A\|_{op}$, which may not be true. Any explanation will be appreciated.

Comment: What is your definition of operator norm? What is your definition of $\| \cdot \|$ for $A$ only? Ponder the definition of the operator norm, it really does follow directly without having to do anything.

Comment: @Kezer I am using the definition $||A||_{op}=\sup_{||x||\leq 1, ||x||\in R^n} ||Ax||$. Yeah, everyone says it is straightforward from its definition, but I cannot see it:( The definition of $||\cdot||$ is just common Euclidean norm (Frobenius norm in this case). There shouldn't be any confusion on this part.

Comment: I was asking about $\|\cdot \|$ because you were talking about $\|A \|$ which often denotes the (induced) operator norm. Here's a definition where it's a bit easier to see: $\|A\|_{\operatorname{op}} = \sup_{v \neq 0} \frac{\|Av\|}{|v|}$. You only have to show that the definitions are equivalent (though Theoretical Economist has actually already done that).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that $\| v \| \neq 0$, because otherwise there is nothing to prove.

By definition, we then have that $$\frac{\| Av \|}{\| v \|} = \left\|A \frac{v}{\| v \|} \right\| \le \| A \|_{op}. $$

The inequality follows from the fact that $$ \left\| \frac{v}{\|v\|} \right\| =1. $$