# Why is $\| T \frac{x}{\|x\|_E} \|_F \leq \|T \|$?

Tags: functional-analysis

Why is $\| T \frac{x}{\|x\|_E} \|_F \leq \|T \|$?

Where $T$ is a linear operator $T: E \rightarrow F$.

Intuitively $\frac{x}{\|x\|_E}=1$.

Comment: $x/\|x\|_E$ is a vector; how can it be equal to $1$?

Comment: They mean that it has norm $1$.

Answer (score 1):

If $||T||$ denotes the operator norm of $T$, then we know that
$$\left\lVert T\frac{x}{||x||_E}\right\lVert_F\leq||T||\cdot \left\lVert \frac{x}{||x||_E}\right\lVert_E=||T||\cdot\frac{1}{||x||_E}||x||_E=||T||,$$ by the operator norm inequality.

EDIT: It looks like the question is to prove the operator norm inequality (which makes more sense, since otherwise it's trivial). It seems like you might be confused on the last step, so I'll clarify it.

The operator norm inequality: $$||Tx||_F\leq ||T||\cdot ||x||_E.$$
*Proof.* If $x=0,$ then the result is obvious, so suppose not. Then,
$$\left\lVert T\left(\frac{x}{||x||_E}\right)\right\lVert_F\leq\sup_{||y||_E=1}||Ty||_F=||T||,$$  and so $$||Tx||_F\leq ||T|| ||x||_E.$$ This hinges on the fact that $$\left\lVert\frac{x}{||x||_E}\right\lVert_E=1,$$ and the operator norm involves a sup over all elements of norm $1$.

Comment: I wonder if one could've used the $\|ST\| \leq \|S\| \|T\|$ for composite operator? Or is that the one that you used?

Comment: Or do you use boundedness of $T$ and select $C=\|T\|< \infty$?

Comment: The proof of the composite result actually comes from the operator norm inequality! (That is, $||Tx||\leq ||T|| \cdot ||x||).$

Comment: Also yes, we're using that $T$ is bounded here, since the operator norm is defined on the space of bounded operators.

Comment: The referred inequality: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3136508/a-direct-result-from-the-definition-of-operator-norm-av-leq-a-op-v

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that you hadn't proved it yet. I'll add in a proof.

Comment: I've edited my post to add in a proof.

Answer (score 0):

Recall how $||T||$ defined. Then, the inequality follows directly from the definition.

$$
||T||:=\sup_{||y||_E=1}||Ty||_F
$$
So, if you give a particular unit vector $y=x/||x||_E$, we have by the above definition 
$$
||T(x/||x||_E)||\leq\sup_{||y||_E=1}||Ty||_F=||T||
$$

Comment: I'm sorry, but what does this add to my answer? It seems redundant, especially given that they were posted with a sizable gap between them.

Comment: @cmk Brevity. To be honest I didn't read yours in full before posting but noticed it was long for what was being asked.

Comment: Fair enough, mine is longer than necessary. The reason is because I didn't know at first that they didn't know the operator norm inequality, so at first I proved it trivially, then edited after talking with them.

Comment: If it's ok with you, I'll leave this up in case it is helpful to op or others. I am definitely not trying to take away from your work.

Comment: Sure, that's perfectly fine!